# Issue with KQL / Kusto distinct, extend and project

Tags: distinct, project, extend, azure-data-explorer, kql

I don't really understand what's the issue if you want to use the command distinct and distinct count AFTER a project or extend operators.

```
let planting_table = ['events.all'] 
    | where FullName_Name == "plant_seed" 
    | extend SeedName = EventData.Payload.SeedName,
        OasisName = EventData.Payload.OasisName,
        TileName = EventData.Payload.TileName
    | project-away SchemaVersion, FullName_Namespace, Entity_Id, Entity_Type,
        EntityLineage_title, EventData, EntityLineage_title_player_account,
        EntityLineage_namespace, ExperimentVariants, FullName_Name
    | project-rename id = EntityLineage_master_player_account
;
planting_table
| summarize dcount(SeedName) by id
```

My goal is to make a distinct count of the seedname by ID in Kusto / KQL. How can I do that?
Why I cannot use distinct after a extend or a project operator?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try casting the `dynamic` property named `SeedName` to `string`, using the `tostring()` function, so that you can aggregate over it using the `distinct` operator.

i.e.

```
...
| extend SeedName = tostring(EventData.Payload.SeedName),
...
| summarize dcount(SeedName) by id
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped. Can you explain me why my queries didn't work?

Comment: `EventData.Payload.SeedName` is of type [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic) - you can't aggregate over it without casting to a specific strong type (e.g. `string`)